# ROS2 xacro parsing: ${robot_ip} vs $(arg robot_ip)

Tags: ros2, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I found this does not parse:  `$(arg robot_ip)`

Whereas this does parse: `${robot_ip}`

Do they have different purposes?  And to make things stranger, both varieties seemed to work on my coworker's computer.

Here's the full block of code, if it would be helpful:

```
  <xacro:macro name="load_arm" params="
    parent
    dof
    vision
    prefix
    *origin
    robot_ip
    use_fake_hardware:=false
    fake_sensor_commands:=false">

      <!-- ros2 control include -->
      <xacro:include filename="$(find my_robot_description)/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/urdf/my_robot.ros2_control.xacro" />
      <xacro:my_robot_ros2_control
        name="MyRobotMultiInterfaceHardware" prefix="${prefix}"
        use_fake_hardware="${use_fake_hardware}"
        fake_sensor_commands="${fake_sensor_commands}"
        tf_prefix=""
        robot_ip="${robot_ip}" />
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383014/ros2-xacro-parsing:-%7B613b8de5-2f05-4dd4-ac16-a1aa82852ce3%7D(arg-robot_ip)/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2021-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My understanding is that you would use the arg [rospack command](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Rospack_commands) when attempting to parse a commandline input argument (e.g. `xacro myfile.xacro myarg:=true`).

You can define a default value in your file with`<xacro:arg name="myarg" default="false"/>`, and have them behave similarly to properties, except for the syntax of how you access the value. Rospack commands use parentheses (`$()`)

In the file you attached, `robot_ip` is a *param* input to your macro, not an argument. Parameters are evaluated as macro-local properties, and properties and expressions are all evaluated within braces (`${}`).

As to why parsing `$(arg robot_ip)` works on your coworkers computer and not yours... I'm not entirely sure, but my hunch would be that your coworker's launch script is slightly different and they define the arg somewhere.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1